# 'Android property not found.' error while building Flutter aar

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, aar

How to fix `Android property not found` error while `flutter build aar`?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Initialization script '/Users/username/sdk/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/aar_init_script.gradle' line: 15
* What went wrong:
Android property not found.
```

Comment: what's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all plugins, if they have not `android` module, then you should add. In my case, my colleague developed iOS related plugin and removed Android part, because it was intended only for iOS.

Your plugins (in our case it's `ios_status_bar` plugin) should contain both `android` and `ios` folders. If you delete `android` you'll get the error `Android property not found`

[image]

Comment: what does that mean exactly? my project was running fine until I updated flutter. not really sure what to do here

Comment: @ElJazouli I added an explanation to the answer. Check again plz. Do you sure that you didn't add any plugins to the project?

Answer (score 1):

Go to this File "/Users/username/sdk/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/aar_init_script.gradle"

And in `if (!project.hasProperty("android")) {
    throw new GradleException(project.toString())
        throw new GradleException("Android property not found.")
    }`

add the project.toString line to the file and run

```
build flutter aar -v
```

Now you will get the conflicting plugin name Ex : url_launcher_mac_os

Now go to .pubcache and delete that folder and run the

```
build flutter aar -v
```

If you dont get conflicting plugins then your build will be successful.

Comment: It's totally worked, This should be the valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

This means, that whatever `build.gradle` is being processed does not feature any `android` configuration block. Besides, building an `ios_status_bar` for Android is highly questionable.